# JAX-WS handler - handleMessage is not running

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, handler

I used wizard in Eclipse to add JAX-WS Handler to my project. It implementes SOAPHandler.

Then, in Project Explorer, under **JAX-WS Web Services > Service Endpoint Interfaces > MyServiceSoap**, I used option to Configure Handlers. I pointed to my Handler class and new file was created handler-chain.xml in the same folder where my MyServiceSoap.java file is.

I've looked into my MyServiceSoap.java and I see declaration @HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")

So, as far as I know, all pieces are in place. But, when I attempt to call this service, 
handleMessage never gets called.

Here is my handleMessage code:

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        return true;
}
```

I set break point in this method with hope that I will be able to see content of the message that is being sent to remote web service.
I also have to note that currently I am getting error "WebServiceException: No Content-type in the header" when I attempt to use this service. So, maybe, this error is happening before handleMessage has chance to run.

I would appreciate it if anybody can provide more light to this subject. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct. The request never made it as far as the handler, much less the web service impl itself. Whatever you're consuming this service with, it's not setting the `Content-type` header (which should be `application/xml`)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but my client was generated by maven using jaxws:wsimport. My Handler never was called, so the solution was to declare `@HandlerChain(file="MyHandlerFile.xml")`, the Xml file (in this case) should be inside in the same package where is your class, example:

```
com.my.package.MyClientWS.java
com.my.package.MyHandlerFile.xml
```

Declaring annotation:

```
@WebService(.....)
@HandlerChain(file="MyHandlerFile.xml")<br>
public class MyClientWS extends Service ....
```

Handler Chain File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>package.to.my.MyHandler<handler-name>
      <handler-class>package.to.my.MyHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

Comment: Same package is the solution to my problem, too. +1 and a cookie to @Gustavo Anatoly :)